# Need VBA to recognize date and not just numbers

Tags: excel, vba

In my code, it is supposed to check if the date exists in column a and if so ask if the entry should be replaced. however I cant get it to read dates, with numbers its fine. Code is:

```
Dim Answer As Integer
  Dim iRow As Long
  Dim Msg As String
  Dim PartCell As Range
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RngEnd As Range
  Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("OP")

   'get all the database entires
    Set Rng = ws.Range("A2")
    Set RngEnd = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    Set Rng = IIf(RngEnd.Row < Rng.Row, Rng, ws.Range(Rng, RngEnd))


   'Check if Date for Entry exits in database
    Set PartCell = Rng.Find(OPdate, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False)
      If Not PartCell Is Nothing Then
        Msg = "Entry for '" & OPdate & "' has already been entered." & vbCrLf _
            & "Do wish to overwrite this record?"
        Answer = MsgBox(Msg, vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
        If Answer = vbNo Then Exit Sub
        iRow = PartCell.Row
      Else
        iRow = RngEnd.Row + 1
      End If

   'copy the data to the database
    ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.OPdate.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.OPst.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.OPia.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you have not defined your date variable `OPdate` anywhere, i.e. you need to add something like:

```
Dim OPdate As Date
OPdate = Date         'Date returns current date
```